# How do I skip 404s in the Wayback machine?

Tags: archive.org

The [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php) seems to archive 404 pages as well as actual content.
For example [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://edition.cnn.com/2004/TECH/biztech/06/10/microsoft.tiered.pricing.ap/index.html) has a ton of 404 pages, and only the first few copies have actual content.

Is there any way to just show the non-404-pages in the calender view? And/or is there any way to (automatically) go to the latest non-404 copy in the archive?

---

There is a [JSON API](http://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php) that seems to return the latest successfully (non-404) archived copy. For my example it looks like [this](http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=http://edition.cnn.com/2004/TECH/biztech/06/10/microsoft.tiered.pricing.ap/index.html). It could possibly be utilized by a bookmarklet or addon or something.

This script uses that API, but it is for webmasters:
http://blog.archive.org/2013/10/24/web-archive-404-handler-for-webmasters/

Comment: I read on the wiki about a plug-in / add-on you can install on Firefox that will automatically detect a 404 error page in Wayback Machine. I am not entirely sure if this is the answer you were looking for, but if so, I will convert the comment to an answer.                                                         http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Using_the_Wayback_Machine

Comment: I believe the description on Wikipedia is a bit unclear. What I think the addon does is detect 404-pages and redirect to the Wayback Machine. Anyways, it doesn't work with new versions of Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently using the following bookmarklet:

```
var f = function(jsn){window.location.href=jsn.archived_snapshots.closest.url;};var d = document,z=d.createElement('script'),b=d.body,l=d.location;z.setAttribute('src','https://archive.org/wayback/available?url='+encodeURIComponent(l.href)+'&callback=f');z.setAttribute('type', "application/javascript");b.appendChild(z);void(0);
```

or for sites where I haven't enabled javascript (in the NoScript addon) i use

```
javascript:(function(){window.location=window.location.toString().replace(/^/,"http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=");})()
```

followed by

```
javascript:(function(){a=JSON.parse(document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerHTML);window.location=a.archived_snapshots.closest.url;})()
```

---

This uses the [API](http://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php) I mentioned above in the question. They are tested in Firefox 32.0 and probably contains multiple bugs.